# SQL - Returning only the most recent row

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on aging report for accounts over 30 days and I am joining the "Comment" table because AP wants to see the most recent comment if it exists for a customer.

The comment table can have multiple rows for the same customer for each comment that is attached to that customer with the first record being the oldest comment.

When I join the tables everything works, but it returns the first comment not the latest.

How can I get it to to look for multiple rows for the same customer and then return the most recent comment?

*Note - The comment table does not have dates just a field the starts at 1000 and increases for each new comment row

This is what i have right now:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].No_, 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Line].[Amt_ Rcd_ Not Invoiced], 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purch_ Rcpt_ Header].[Posting Date], 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line].[Comment], 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].[Sell-to Customer No_]
FROM
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header] 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Line] ON dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].No_ = dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Line].[Document No_] 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purch_ Rcpt_ Header] ON dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].No_ = dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purch_ Rcpt_ Header].[Order No_] 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line] ON dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].[Sell-to Customer No_] = dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line].[No_]
WHERE
    (dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purch_ Rcpt_ Header].[Posting Date] < DATEADD(day, - 30, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].No_, 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Line].[Amt_ Rcd_ Not Invoiced], 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purch_ Rcpt_ Header].[Posting Date], 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line].[Comment], 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].[Sell-to Customer No_]
HAVING        
    (dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Line].[Amt_ Rcd_ Not Invoiced] > '0')
ORDER BY 
    dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purch_ Rcpt_ Header].[Posting Date] DESC
```

Comment: As well as your described problem, bear in mind that as you're using only INNER JOINs, if a customer has no comments at all, they won't appear on the report, no matter how old their debt.

Comment: `[posting date] desc` will return the first/latest one, since descending means "newest first". try `asc` instead - oldest first

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```
select customer.*, lastComment.*
from account
cross apply (select top 1 * from comment where
    comment.customerId=customer.customerId order by commentnumber desc) lastComment
where customer.age>30
```

If you need to include customers without comments use `outer apply` instead of `cross apply`

Answer (score 1):

I would use following query:

```
OUTER APPLY
(select top 1 [Comment] from dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line] where dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Purchase Header].[Sell-to Customer No_] = dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line].[No_] order by [Posting Date] desc) Comments
```

Also, use `Comments.[Comment]` in the SELECT statement instead of `dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line].[Comment]`

The dbo.[Pioneer-CO$Comment Line] table should be OUTER APPLY join in the query. Also, order by comments posting date or incremental ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the ID or primary key,  I'd imagine the newer comments have a higher ID. You could join the tables and do a Max(ID) or look for the latest timestamp if you use that on your table.

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL and I was having trouble using the MAX function. Any suggestions on how that code would look?

Comment: @Rkindred lookup [MAX - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx). Microsoft's MSDN is a great resource on syntax and official uses of SQL keywords. Also, understand that unless the function is by itself, you MUST have a column (non-aggregate) that appears in the `SELECT`, also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. For an overview with links to other aggregates, see [AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS - MSDN](https://MSDN.Microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have Customers to Comments relationship is 1 to Many(0).
How about trying something like this,

```
SELECT TOP 1 Customers.*, Comments.*
FROM Customers
JOIN Customers ON Customers.Id = Comments.Id
ORDER BY Comments.Id DESC
```

*Following Added after Bib's comments*

You can also try following

```
SELECT Customers.*, Comments.*
FROM Comments
JOIN
(SELECT MAX(Id) As CId FROM Comments GROUP BY CustomerId) AS CommentsMAX
ON CommentsMAX.CId = Comments.ID
JOIN 
Customers ON Customers.Id = Comments.Id
```

Comment: This will only return one row, It will be the the latest comment and the customer that this comment is linked to